# On trying to open an order from magento backend I am getting this error ? Any help

Tags: orders, ce-1.8.1.0, shipment

```
Magento Commerce
There has been an error processing your request

Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment) with the same id "322" already exist

Trace:

0 /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
1 /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
2 /var/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(154): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
3 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/magent...')
4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
9 /var/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Tolexo_ShippingStatus_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Shipments))
10 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/magent...')
11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
14 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
15 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
16 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
17 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
18 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
19 /var/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
20 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/magent...')
21 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
22 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
23 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
24 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
25 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
26 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
27 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
28 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
29 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
30 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
31 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
32 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
33 /var/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
34 {main}
```

Comment: Please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to learn how to debug and write better error reportings. This are too less informations to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tolexo_ShippingStatus_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Shipments` This tab is pulling out the same shipment twice in the same collection, maybe because of the way it's joined. You can't have two different objects with the same id in a DB collection. you should take it up with your vendor for that extension.